# Pattern Matching Algorithm for Serial Numbers

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have two csv files which contain serial numbers for equipment. One of them has the correct serial numbers directly scanned from the equipment. The other report is from our inventory system. I want to cross-reference both lists to see which items are on both lists and at the same time I want to check possible matches for serial numbers.

I will be programming this in java.

Example 1:

List A Serial Number: "AGJC-021645"

List B Serial Number: "AGJC-021645"

That would be an exact match. But that one is fairly easy.

Example 2:

List A Serial Number: "AGJC-01254"

Possible Matches from List B: "AGJC-01253", "AGJC-00254", etc etc....

Then with this I can tell my inventory staff to verify them. It could have been a typing error when they entered it into the system.

Worst case scenario I'd have to create my own pattern matching algorithm but there could be some library that already does this.

Thanks

Comment: And, do you try something?, do you have some code?

Comment: Yeah. I already have some java code that will read the csv files, and everything to a map or list. I'm now looking into the best way to compare them

Comment: Please add your java code to see your approaches and add a more detailed question about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I would compute the similarity using the Levenshtein distance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance, instead of doing pattern matching.

> In information theory and computer science, the Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other. The phrase edit distance is often used to refer specifically to Levenshtein distance. It is named after Vladimir Levenshtein, who considered this distance in 1965. It is closely related to pairwise string alignments.

You can find a Java implementation at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [standard Java String pattern matching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You of course then need to define your own RegEx that fits your serial numbers.